# Using Intermediate Value Theorem to prove I can be at the same elevation 8 hours apart during a 16hour trip up a canyon

Tags: calculus, functions

I need some help with generating a solution for this problem using IVT.
The Problem: You are on a hiking trip. You start at the bottom of the canyon and it takes you 8 hours to reach the top. The way down also take you 8 hours. Is it possible that you were at the same height/elevation whilst going up the canyon as you were going down the canyon at exactly 8 hours apart? This is under the assumption that the rate of hiking up to the top is not equal to the rate of hiking down from the top. So far I have tried splitting the first 8 hours as a function h(t) and the latter half of the trip being g(t), where t is time in hours. However, I am quite confused with what steps to take.
I have also developed these equations: h(0) = g(8) , h(8) = g(0), h(16) = h(0), h(t+8) = g(t). Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Draw a sketch of height vs time on the way up and overlay the height vs time on the way down, but with the time delayed 8h. Look at the intersection.

Comment: Isn’t  the domain $[0,8]$ for both? Also, say in words what $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ are and what you need to prove.

Comment: You're very close. Consider the function $f(t) = h(t) - g(t)$ and how it behaves over the course of the trip.

Comment: You don't need to split them into different functions. Let $h:[0,16] \to \mathbb R$ via $g(t) = $ height at time $t$.  Now let $j:[0,8]\to \mathbb R$ be $h(t+8) - gh(t)$.  So $j(0) = h(8) - h(0)=top - bottom > 0$.  And $j(8)= h(16)-h(8) = bottom - top < 0$.  So there is $t: 0< 8$ were $j(t) = 0$.  That would mean $j(t) = h(t+8)-h(t) = 0$ or $h(t+8) = h(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality say the height of the canyon is $1$. Then $h(0)=g(8)=0$ and $h(8)=g(0)=1$; defining $d(t)=g(t)-h(t)$, which is continuous, we have $d(0)=1$ and $d(8)=-1$. Therefore by the intermediate value theorem there is some $c\in(0,1)$ with $d(c)=g(c)-h(c)=0$; remembering that $c$ on $g$ is exactly $8$ hours ahead of $c$ on $h$, we have the proof that there are two points on the journey $8$ hours apart at the same height.